# Slow response to a recursive rawlist request in phpseclib

Tags: phpseclib

I wrote a PHP program that performs a rawlist function on a remote server with many (about 1000) directories. The phpseclib SFTP rawlist method works, but it takes over 12 minutes to traverse the directory tree on the server. On the other hand, the plain old FTP rawlist function (ftp_rawlist) returns the same results in about 30 seconds.

I understand that an SSH connection adds overhead because of encryption, but this seems excessive. I've had the same SFTP results from PHP 5.3 and 5.4 systems running on Windows Server 2012 and Windows 7, resp. Both installation have mcrypt and gmp enabled.

Here is a basic version of the program I've been testing with:

```
<?php
  set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'C:/path-to/phpseclib');

  include 'Crypt/RSA.php';
  include 'Net/SFTP.php';

  $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
  $priKey = file_get_contents('C:/path-to/my_private_key.ppk');
  $rsa->loadKey($priKey);

  $sftp = new Net_SFTP('my_ssh_server_URI', 22);
  if (!$sftp->login('my_user_id', $rsa)) {
    exit("Login Failed\n");
  }

  print_r($sftp->rawlist('starting_directory', true));
?>
```

I just wonder if someone has run into the same issue with the SFTP "_list" method and come up with a work-around to improve performance. Thank you.

Comment: My guess: with FTP you can do `LIST -R` that'll make the server compile and return the directory list. SFTP has no such option so phpseclib emulates it by opening each directory one by one. And it's faster if the server does it instead of the client.

Comment: Neubert, thank you - that makes a lot of sense. Apparently not all FTP Servers honor the "-R" option on the LIST command, but the one I'm connecting to must, which would explain why the PHP ftp_rawlist function can recurse the directory tree so much faster than the phpseclib function. In spite of the extra minutes, phpseclib works fine and it's a great tool.