# PHPSECLIB read the total size of directory?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

```
echo $sftp->size('foldername');
```

This code only return the default size of directory 4096

How can i read the total size, used space of the directory/folder that contains many files?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this with SFTP I guess you could do something like this (untested):

```
$size = 0;
$files = $sftp->rawlist('foldername', true);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $size+= $file['size'];
}
```

Note that recursive directory listings with SFTP [can be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502422/slow-response-to-a-recursive-rawlist-request-in-phpseclib#comment45341237_28502422).

Alternatively, you could do `$sftp->exec('du -s foldername');`. That'd be the fastest way. Since SFTP extends SSH2 with phpseclib `exec` is a valid method.

Comment: +1 - Though worth noting that the `$sftp->exec('du -s foldername')` is not SFTP solution anymore. It requires a shell access and is *nix specific.